# Import components as array in Angular standalone components

Tags: angular

I created a library using standalone components.
In this library, I export related components in arrays like this:

```
export const TABLE_COMPONENTS: Type<any>[] = [
  TableComponent,
  TableHeaderComponent,
  TableBodyRowDirective,
  TableHeaderRowDirective,
  TableBodyEmptyRowDirective,
  TableFooterRowDirective,
  TableFirstRowDirective,
  TableFilterIconDirective,
  TableLastRowDirective
];
```

But when I try to use this array in the consuming application it does not work.
I tried like this:

```
imports: [
    TABLE_COMPONENTS
],
```

But I get the error "'imports' must be an array of components, directives, pipes, or NgModules. Value is a reference to 'TABLE_COMPONENTS'". I also tried:

- Using the spread operator to "flatten" the array
- Exporting components as `Provider[]` or `any[]`
- Exporting components without specifying the type of the array

I even tried using the same syntax as in the official Angular guide

```
export const TABLE_COMPONENTS = [
  TableComponent,
  TableHeaderComponent,
  TableBodyRowDirective,
  TableHeaderRowDirective,
  TableBodyEmptyRowDirective,
  TableFooterRowDirective,
  TableFirstRowDirective,
  TableFilterIconDirective,
  TableLastRowDirective
] as const;
```

The weird thing with this syntax is that vscode does not complain, but then, I get the error above during the compilation.

Does anyone know how to export related components into an array in order to import them at once instead of one by one?

**Updated:**

One important thing I forgot to mention is that I have a playground application for this library that references it directly (so not via a npm link or by installing the package) and there, it works. The issue seems to appear when I consume the library from a different application where I install it.

Comment: Not really but I do need to import other components as well. so it would be something like `imports: [ MyComponent, TABLE_COMPONENTS, MyOtherComponent ]`. I tried with the spread operator but it does not work. I don't get it as at the end, this is simply an array of types...

Comment: Not in the case of standalone components ;-) The `imports` I'm showing here is one of a component.

Comment: Ups! did not pay attention that you are dealing with standalone components.

Comment: Could not reproduce your problem. Is that right how I did it?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mt3alb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I updated the OP to add an interesting point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're making a 2-dimensional array the way you have it set up.

```
export const TABLE_COMPONENTS: Type<any>[] = [
  TableComponent,
  TableHeaderComponent,
  TableBodyRowDirective,
  TableHeaderRowDirective,
  TableBodyEmptyRowDirective,
  TableFooterRowDirective,
  TableFirstRowDirective,
  TableFilterIconDirective,
  TableLastRowDirective
];


imports: [
    TABLE_COMPONENTS
],
```

After this, your `imports` will be an array with 1 element, which is itself an array. If you use the spread operator, it should work as you intend:

```
imports: [
    ...TABLE_COMPONENTS
]
```

You may also need to remove the `Type<any>[]` typing from the `TABLE_COMPONENTS` to coerce it

Here's a working StackBlitz example showing it working as expected with no typing, and using the spread operator: [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wxjdty?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow but as said in the OP, I think I already did that and it didn't work. CHeck out the OP, I wrote an update.

Comment: I'm getting an error related to Angular being unable to statically analyze the array,

`'imports' must be an array of components, directives, pipes, or NgModules.
  Value is of type '[
(not statically analyzable), (not statically analyzable), (not statically analyzable), RouterModule, SharedModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ButtonDirective, SearchFieldComponent, IconComponent]`