# How to use angular component when using barrels module (shared module)

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components, barrel-import

I'd like to migrate my project to use standalone component.

But I'm using quite a lot of "Barrel imports" *[What's a barrel?](https://mwiza.medium.com/make-use-of-angular-barrels-for-better-organization-of-imports-db0429c22e58)*

So, I just

1. added the following to my component

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  // ...
})
export class SharedComponent { 
 //... 
}
```

2. Removed the `shared-component.module.ts` file
3. Replace the "export" section in my barrel module

```js
// shared.module.ts
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    // Shared
    SharedFormsModule,

    // Modals
    SharedComponent, // <-- Error (1)
    // ...
```

I do get the following error

Error (1)

> Can't be exported from this NgModule, as it must be imported first

So tried to declare it first

```js
// shared.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ModalDeleteArchiveComponent], // <-- Error (2)
  exports: [
    // Shared
    SharedFormsModule,

    // Modals
    SharedComponent, // <-- Error (1)
    // ...
```

But now I do get

Error (2)

> Component ModalDeleteArchiveComponent is standalone, and cannot be declared in an NgModule. Did you mean to import it instead?

Somebody knows how to make this work?

Comment: Update has made the question less clear. I think you’re after something like the Stackblitz in the comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75088006/4711754)?

Comment: Related open issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/48089

Comment: @AndrewAllen Agreed, I reverted it. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

standalone components should be listed in `imports`, not in `declarations`.

```js
// shared.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ModalDeleteArchiveComponent], // <-- Wrong
  imports: [ModalDeleteArchiveComponent], // <-- Correct
  exports: [
    // Shared
    SharedFormsModule,

    // Modals
    SharedComponent,
    // ...
  ]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, since standalone components are modules under the hood. (Virtual Modules, more: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/xnyumv/how_are_standalone_components_implemented_under/)

Comment: Thx, but I really have to export them, because I wish to keep the barrel module logic. Or how can this being then used in the `third.module.ts`. I've updated my question to add an explanation of what a barrel module is. @Don FYI

Comment: You can still simply export them inside your barrel-module. Just be sure at the same time to not have them inside the declarations array, but inside the import array of your barrel-module.